# why Im having String indexing problem in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to understand why I'm having the same index again when I apply .index or .find
why I'm getting the same index '2' again why not '3'? when a letter is repeated, and what is the alternative way to get an index 3 for the second 'l'

```
text = 'Hello'
for i in text:
    print(text.index(i))
```

the output is:

```
0
1
2
2
4
```

Comment: Because `index` always returns the index of the first occurrence

Comment: for the second part of your question - look at `enumerate()` function to get all index of each and every char in the string. eg. `for idx, ch in enumerate(text):`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because `.index()` returns the **lowest** or **first** index of the substring within the string. Since the first occurrence of `l` in `hello` is at index 2, you'll always get 2 for `"hello".index("l")`.

So when you're iterating through the characters of `hello`, you get 2 twice and never 3 (for the second `l`). Expanded into separate lines, it looks like this:

```py
"hello".index("h")   # = 0
"hello".index("e")   # = 1
"hello".index("l")   # = 2
"hello".index("l")   # = 2
"hello".index("o")   # = 4
```

**Edit: Alternative way to get all indices**:

One way to print all the indices (although not sure how useful this is since it just prints consecutive numbers) is to remove the character you just read from the string:

```py
removed = 0
string = "hello world"    # original string
for char in string:
  print("{} at index {}".format(char, string.index(char) + removed))  # index is index() + how many chars we've removed
  string = string[1:]    # remove the char we just read
  removed +=1            # increment removed count
```

Answer (score 1):

```
text = 'Hello'
for idx, ch in enumerate(text):
    print(f'char {ch} at index {idx}')
```

output

```
char H at index 0
char e at index 1
char l at index 2
char l at index 3
char o at index 4
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the second occurance, you should search in the substring after the first occurance

```py
text = 'Hello'
first_index = text.index('l')
print('First index:', first_index)

second_index = text.index('l', first_index+1) # Search in the substring after the first occurance
print('Second index:', second_index)
```

The output is:

```
First index: 2
Second index: 3
```